# How many people use Google or Facebook to sign up to other apps

Tags: login, register

I notice that a vast majority of apps nowadays prioritise login with Facebook, Google, or other platforms for Sign Up. Usually you see a button with Facebook, one with Google, and the last option is sign up with email.

Are there any statistics showing what users preferences are? I would assume that most people would sign up with Google or Facebook and it is also my preference but I would like to know if there are any reports on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're referring to is called Single Sign-On or SSO for short. There are multiple options including Facebook, Google, LinkedIn, and Twitter.

I searched and couldn't find any recent reports about SSO but there is one that was published in 2015: http://learn.addshoppers.com/2015/#

Here's another good resource on what SSO is and advantages/disadvanges: https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/single-sign-on

Comment: Thank you for the link. I found this: 
How many people choose to use social login versus traditional login?
The average is 20% and ranges from 5% to 40%

I am curious to see the 2020 numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Don't have any reports but can give data from one of the services I run.

My service offers Google & Facebook login methods.

I have,

```
30,024 users
26,034 confirmed users (users who have confirmed their email)
14,264 users who have Google or Facebook linked to their account
11,599 users who linked Google
2,717 users who linked Facebook
58 users who linked both Google & Facebook (1 was me testing xD)
```

My service positions Regular email registration first & then shows SNS related buttons. The button order is Google first & Facebook second.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a bunch of numbers online for this. The search keyword that seems to work here is "Social Login" (though the technical term is SSO).

> In Q2 2016, almost 93% consumers preferred social login over
> traditional email registration on websites.

https://www.loginradius.com/blog/start-with-identity/customer-identity-preference-trends-q2-2016/

I couldn't download the 2020 report, but it's [here](https://www.loginradius.com/resource/digital-identity-trends-2020/).

> Google: 58% Email: 23% Facebook: 19%. Most of our users are around 18yo.

> Email 50% Facebook 35% Google 15%

> 40% email, 30% Google, 30% Facebook

This is some of the self reporting from a survey on [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16666373). In general, while the numbers differ, it looks like even in a tech-heavy crowd you're looking at around 60-70% social login usage.